# firebase List of Data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a friends list extension for an online browser game I play. Every user has a list of friends. I'm trying to figure out the best way to update this list when a new friend is added. Right now I get their friends as a string, add a colon followed by the new friends name, then set the new string back as their friends string. I feel however there is a better way to do so, as this doesn't look right: `"Friend0:Friend1:Friend2"`

My code for this process looks like this:

```
var reqName = $('#addFriendText').val();  // Name to be added
var name = args['name'];                  // Current users name
firebase.database().ref('/users/' + name).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
   var friends = snapshot.val()['friends'];  // Get friends string
   newFriends = friends + ':' + reqName;     // Make new friends string
   var dbRef = firebase.database().ref('users');
   var obj = {};
   obj[name] = {'friends':newFriends};       
   dbRef.update(obj).then(function(){        // Store new friends string
       console.log('db updated');
   });
});
```

Is there a cleaner way to do what I'm trying to do? I heard arrays aren't optimal but I need some sort of list structure. For reference, the data structure looks like this in my console:

[image: data]

Comment: Read the Firebase documentation on [storing lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/save-data#append_to_a_list_of_data) and [creating data that scales](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#fanout).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you want to retrieve them, a better approach would be this:

```
"users": {
  "Cap": {
    "friends": {
      "user1": true,
      "user2": true
    }
  }
}
```

I suggest reading [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data)